# Custom View not updating

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So I'm following this tutorial to create a custom `UITableCellView` using the interface builder. I created a xib file with a `UITableViewCell` that has a custom `UITableViewCell` as its class. In said class I have -

```
@interface SearchResultCell : UITableViewCell
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *restaurantImage;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *restaurantName;
@end
```

In the interface builder file for the custom `UITableViewCell`, in the connections menu I dragged `restaurantImage` to the `UIImageView` in the custom `UITableViewCell`, and the label to the `restaurantName`.

Then in the place where my table is drawn I do this -

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SearchResultCell *cell = [self.resultTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *rowData = self.resultsTuples[indexPath.row];
    NSString* restaurantTitle = rowData[@"$element"][@"Title"];
    cell.restaurantName.text = restaurantTitle;
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SearchResultCell"
                                bundle:nil];
    [self.resultTable registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Doing `cell.restaurantName.text = restaurantTitle` doesn't result in anything. However, doing `cell.textLabel.text = restaurantTitle` does work.

Why is my label not updating?

Comment: Your class seems to be called `TooviaSearchResultCell`, but you're referring to another class, `SearchResultCell` in your method.

Comment: Is the cell's style set to "Custom" in IB?

Comment: sorry- copy and paste error- and yes, style is set to Custom

Comment: After you dequeue the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, put in a log [cell class] and see if it gives you SearchResultCell. Also log cell.restaurantName and see what it gives.

Comment: This could be the issue with your **CustomCell** which you have created. Check all the things properly.

Comment: cell.restaurantName is printing properly - this is the output from log(cell) -

<SearchResultCell: 0x121c8d40; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 367 245); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x121c8ed0>>

Comment: Ok Check the  UIColor of the text for cell.restaurantName . ..

Comment: May be the Color of background and labeltext are same...!!!

Comment: er - the labeltext has black as a colour

Comment: Try giving your restaurantName label a background color to see if it even shows up in the cell.

Comment: ok - so I set it in the interface builder. Nothing showed up - do I need to do an alloc for the label in some init method in my custom class? I've tried allocing in the initWithStyle method, but nothing happened

Comment: No, you don't need to do that if you've aded the label in the xib. When you log cell.restaurantName does it give you the frame?

Comment: yeah - I get this - <UILabel: 0xa65a460; frame = (294 96; 110 38); text = 'San Francisco Green Film ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa65a500>>

Comment: Is your cell 245 points high when you run the app (as it says in the log of cell)?

Comment: er...how do I check that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43162/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-praks5432)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells may not be the correct height to show your custom label. Since you made the cells 245 points high in the xib, you should implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:, and return 245.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you do this?

   ```
   @synthesize restaurantImage;
   @synthesize restaurantName;
   ```
2. After that, in your code:

   ```
   restaurantName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:yourRestaurantNameFrame];
   //other attribute
   [self.contentView addSubview:restaurantName];
   ```